# C# How to find out how long are two different numbers in a string?

Tags: c#, file, count, int, substring

i want to know how big are the 2 numbers in the string. The difficult thing is that the 2 numbers are variables and i dont know how long they are, they are growing with time. The Program write the variables into a txt file. Now i read all lines of the file and put it into a string. After this i need the two numbers as an int to determine the two variables, to keep counting with them.
Example code:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
string text = "";

//imagine foreach keypress B num1++ and foreach keypress N num2++
File.WriteAllLines("C:\\ExampleFile", $"Num1 = {num1}, Num2 = {num2}!");

// between this is a programm restart

text = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\ExampleFile");

//now iwant to get the value of num1 and num2 
text.substring(6, num1.length) //something like this idk

num1 = ?
num2 = ?
```

Hope you will understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using SubString, you could use Regular Expressions for the purpose. For example,

```
var regex = new Regex(@"=\s*(?<Number1>\d*),\s*Num2\s*=\s*(?<Number2>\d*)");

var matches = regex.Match(text);
if(matches.Success)
{
    var num1 = Int32.Parse(matches.Groups["Number1"].Value);
    var num2 = Int32.Parse(matches.Groups["Number2"].Value);
}
```

The regex indicates two groups (indicated by "(?[expression])"), the first consisting of a number preceeded by an '=' and whitespaces. The first group would be followed by a "," & whitespace characters. This is followed by the Second group,  is preceeded by the text"Num2" and has the same definition has the first group.

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7LddsP)

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Could you explain the regex pattern :) I dont understand it :/

Comment: @Luuke I have added a brief description. Please let me know if you need more

Answer (score 0):

You could print them to `Strings` using `ToString()`, then call [String.Lenght](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length). While string is not technically a char[] (even if it is propably wrapping one), it can be treated like one. However that might give you the wrong results. The string representation to print out to or parse from, is determined in large parts by the culture of the user as set in Windows.

And aside from differing thousands and decimal seperators, there are even different ideas how to group numbers between cultures - like the Indian [Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) and [Crore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore).

If the question is about the number of digits in base 10, this would not work. However I remember a recent case, where someone figured out how many repeating digits the decimal part of a division had. I think this code would be a proper adaptation to your case:

```
int current = Input;
int Digits = 1;

while(current >= 10){
  current = current / 10;
  Digits++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string on your delimiter characters and use it as an array.

```
var input = $"Num1 = 123, Num2 = 456!"

//Results in the array { "Num1","123","Num2","456" }
var tokens = input.Split(new char[] { '=', ',', ' ', '!'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var num1 = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
var num2 = int.Parse(tokens[3]);
```